# Database rollback when ValidationEventHandler is fired on XmlSchemaValidationException

Tags: .net, exception, event-handling, using

I have an `.xml` document which I am parsing and inserting into a database in a transaction. I'd like to rollback any changes if validation errors are found. Because the documents could be large, I'm using `XmlReaderSettings`, and a `ValidationEventHandler`.

Here are the snippets. I instantiate `XmlReaderSettings` and attach a `ValidationEventHandler`.

```
settings.ValidationEventHandler += new System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);


private void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
    {
        throw new XmlSchemaValidationException();
    }
}
```

I then try-catch, and rollback on any exception.

```
using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (OracleCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        using (OracleTransaction trans = oracleConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
        {
            try
            {    
                conn.Transaction = trans;
                using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings))
                {
                    // parsing
                }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                trans.Rollback();
             }
         }
    }
}
```

I am expecting that:

- the connection, transaction, command and xmlreader will all be disposed of properly even if an exception occurs
- the transaction will be rolled back on any exceptions (if the connection manages to open)

Am I wrong? How can I fix the code if I am?

Comment: Don't know if Oracle support it, but you should also take a look at the [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) class

Comment: @SteveB Thanks! I didn't know about that class. I'll research if it's available for my client-database combination.

Comment: @SteveB Unfortunately, it seems to require "Oracle Services for MTS" and I can't be sure it is present on the target environment.